# I'm trying to write a code to check if a given item exist in an array and set a variable as true or false if not

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have this array,

```
const prices = [
  ["bread", 20],
  ["apple", 50],
  ["noodles", 100],
  ["beef", 40],
  ["milk", 32],
  ["coke", 25],
];
```

and here's my code,

```
function addItemToCart(item) {

  let isValidItem = false;

  for(i=0; i<prices.length; i++){
    if(item = prices[i]){
      isValidItem != true;
    } else{
      isValidItem = true;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm new to Javascript and I'll really appreciate any help and recommendations.

Comment: Did my answer help you? If not, please let me know so I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at all great [Array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) that are available.

You can write very readable code like this:

```
let isValidItem = prices.includes(item)
```